# Difference between these two TypeScript import statements

Tags: typescript

I am used to this TypeScript import statement, which imports the "Component" class from the "angular/core" module:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
```

But I have also seen other import statements such as this:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
```

What does the second one do, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation it's called [Import a module for side-effects only](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only):

> Though not recommended practice, some modules set up some global state
>   that can be used by other modules. These modules may not have any
>   exports, or the consumer is not interested in any of their exports.

In the example you posted this import probably adds the `Symbol` es6 polyfill so that the compiler will find it even without targeting es6

Answer (score 1):

The second references a javascript file directly, `\node_modules\core-js\es6\symbol.js` in this case, and any export statements in that file will be loaded into your program.

symbol.js looks like this:

```
require('../modules/es6.symbol');
require('../modules/es6.object.to-string');
module.exports = require('../modules/_core').Symbol;
```

So you are getting the .Symbol object from the _core.js module.